# Problem with Binomial distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Can you help me with this problem - how to solve it or what methods to use?

1. The amount of burnt lamps in a device is a binomially distributed random variable $$X \sim \mathcal{Bin}(3, 1/3)$$
   The probabilities of the device breaking after the failure of one, two or three lamps are respectively
   $$ p_{1} = 0.5, p_{2} = 0.6, p_{3} = 0.8$$

   - a) What is the probability of the device to break?
   - b) If the device is damaged, what is the probability that more than one lamp burned?

Comment: What about if there are no burnt lamps? Is the probability of breakage then $0$

Comment: @AndréNicolas it is not stated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ the event: *the device breaks*. You need to find $P(A)$.

Using the law of total probability, we can write: $$P(A)=\sum_{i=0}^3P(A|X=i)P(X=i)$$

If no lamp is burnt, then we can assume the probability for the device to break is $0$. So $P(A|X=0)=0$.
For $i=1,2,3$, $P(A|X=i)$ is given to you, it's $p_i$.

Now you just have to find $P(X=i)$ for $1\leq i\leq 3$, using the fact that $X\sim B(3,1/3)$.

Comment: This will give me the probably of the device to break which is the answer of point a). 
I will find $P(X = 1), P(X = 2)$ and $P(X = 3)$ by using the probability mass function for a binomial distribution which is $ \binom{n}{x}p^x(1 - p)^{n - x}$
So for point b) should I use Bayes' thorem to find $P(A) - P(X = 1| A)$ ?

Comment: You need to find $P(X\geq 2\vert A)=1-P(X=1\vert A)$